# Windows Integrated Authentication not working on client side

Tags: windows, authentication, team-foundation-server

I'm having a strange problem with Team Foundation Server and Windows Integrated Authentication.

I have two different computers I'm currently using to connect to a single Team Foundation server.
Both computers and the server are on the same Active Directory, which should allow Windows Integrated Authentication to automatically authentify myself when accessing the TFS server.

This configuration works fine on one of the two computers. I can add the server in Visual Studio and connect to it without having to authentify myself.
However, on the second computer, I am unable to use WIA. When I add the TFS server, it asks for my credentials, and then rejects me with an error saying I do not have sufficients rights to connect to the server.

I am interested in any idea which could help me solve this problem :-)

Comment: Try log off from the first computer. Log on to Windows on second one and try add TFS server.

Comment: @J Andwenyi : I was not logged on the second computer when I tried on the first, will try eventually, but I don't think this is the problem. thanks anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing Team Foundation Server cache directory on the machine which had problems.

Apparently, the old references to a previous Team Foudation Server were causing some conflicts when trying to connect to the new server.

The cache directory is located in the `Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation` directory. Delete the `1.0` folder for VS2005, or `2.0` folder for VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem with your `LMCompatibility` setting in the registry.  Take a look at this key on both machines:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa`

Add or modify the key labelled `LMCompatibility` (it's a `dword`) and set it to whatever the working computer has on it, or try it with either `3` or `2`.  Remember to reboot whenever you change it.

Comment: I have no key labelled `LMCompatibility` on both machines. I found a `LMCompatibilityLevel`, but both machines have the same value (1).